# Select query select with Substr returns NULL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to query the name field in the Oracle DB like below

```
select NAME, Substr(NAME,1,instr(NAME,' ') - 1) as SHORTNAME from rm_room
```

what I am trying is if the Name field has space between the string the select only charcters on the left of the space. I am expecting the above query to return

| NAME | SHORTNAME |
| --- | --- |
| AX1 BD | AX1 |
| A1 | A1 |
| BC W1 | BC |

but the issue is if the name field doesnot have space then it is returning null in the SHORTNAME Field

| NAME | SHORTNAME |
| --- | --- |
| AX1 BD | AX1 |
| A1 | NULL |
| BC W1 | BC |

Can we use if condition in the select clause if so how can I check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just use the NVL function which sets a default value instead of null

```
select NAME, NVL(Substr(NAME,1,instr(NAME,' ') - 1),NAME) as SHORTNAME from rm_room
```

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions (see line #7):

```
SQL> with rm_room (name) as
  2    (select 'AX1 BD' from dual union all
  3     select 'A1'     from dual union all
  4     select 'BC W1'  from dual
  5    )
  6  select name,
  7    regexp_substr(name, '^\w+') shortname
  8  from rm_room    ;

NAME   SHORTN
------ ------
AX1 BD AX1
A1     A1
BC W1  BC

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
select NAME,
       CASE instr(NAME,' ')
       WHEN 0
       THEN name
       ELSE Substr(NAME,1,instr(NAME,' ') - 1)
       END as SHORTNAME
from   rm_room
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE rm_room (NAME) AS
SELECT 'AX1 BD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BC W1' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | NAME | SHORTNAME |
> | --- | --- |
> | AX1 BD | AX1 |
> | A1 | A1 |
> | BC W1 | BC |

---

You could also use a regular expression:

```sql
select NAME,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(name, '^[^ ]+') as SHORTNAME
from   rm_room
```

However, they are much slower than simple string functions (even if the code is shorter).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4b29a396048bd5aa81300f49cc74696e)*

Answer (score 1):

Check if the name contains a space or not

```
select NAME,
Case WHEN instr(NAME,' ') > 0 THEN Substr(NAME,1,instr(NAME,' ') - 1) 
Else NAME End as SHORTNAME 
from rm_room
```

It is preferable to use the **Trim function** to cut any spaces at the beginning or end of the room name

```
select NAME,
Case WHEN instr( TRIM(NAME),' ') > 0 THEN Substr(TRIM(NAME),1,instr(TRIM(NAME),' ') - 1) 
Else TRIM(NAME) End as SHORTNAME 
from rm_room
```